# Extract data from an array using OOP way in PHP5

Tags: php, sql

I'm new here and i'm new about PHP5 OOP. I create the db class and relatives functions as connect(), disconnect(), select(), ecc.
My problem and my question is simply to extract data from an array $res (result) and so to expose data in OOP way.

```
 <?php
    include('../php/class/Database.php');

    $db = new database();
    $db->connect();

    $db->select('post','*','post_category','post.Category = post_category.Id','Date DESC','0,10'); // Table name, Column Names, JOIN, WHERE conditions, ORDER BY conditions
    $res = $db->getResult();
    print_r($res);

    $db->disconnect();

    ?>
```

$res return this string with print_r() function:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Id] => 1 [Category] => 1 [Title] => W3C Validation Web [Content] => [Source] => [Link] => [Date] => 2013-12-20 14:15:00 [Author] => Andrea Limoli [ShortDescription] => HTML [LongDescription] => HyperText Markup Language ) [1] => Array ( [Id] => 13 [Category] => 13 [Title] => The art of Typography [Content] => [Source] => [Link] => [Date] => 2013-12-18 00:00:00 [Author] => Andrea Limoli [ShortDescription] => Typography [LongDescription] => Typography ) )
```

This code works but I have a HTML page where I expose the data where I have to fill in these data in div. For example:

```
echo("<div>".$row[Title]."</div>");
```

**I know how expose data in this way but I would know the best way to expose data on HTML page in OOP way.**

My question is: "How can I extract data from $res and use it in OOP way?

Comment: You could convert the array to a stdClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to give you some resources to start learning:

**Try PHP [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)**

The PHP Data Objects (PDO) extension defines a lightweight, consistent interface for accessing databases in PHP.

There are OOP patterns to deal with data:

- Active Record
- [Table gateway](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html)
- ORM (Object Relational Mapper)